# Same album name query result

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to insert albums for singers, for example:

My heart: Singer1

Lovely: Singer1 and Singer3

Touch me: Singer5

Lovely album, is shared between both singers

and so on, while displaying result in PHP, I do like this:

My heart: Singer1
Lovely: Singer1 - Singer3
Touch me: Singer5

By chance, I've got a same album name, which is not shared between singers, and while displaying the result, it shows like below:

**My heart: Singer1 - Singer8**

Lovely: Singer1 - Singer3

Touch me: Singer5

**My heart: Singer1 - Singer8**

However, Singer1 and Singer8 are not sharing this album, I would like to display as below:

**My heart: Singer1**

Lovely: Singer1 - Singer3

Touch me: Singer5

**My heart: Singer8**

```
$queryy = 'SELECT silsila_ar, id_shksj 
           FROM mariyat_silsila 
              JOIN mariyat_silsila_join on 
                  mariyat_silsila.ids = mariyat_silsila_join.id_silsilaj 
           WHERE mariyat_silsila.silsila_tran = "'.$albumName.'"';
echo $queryy.'<br>';      
$reqq = $connexion->query($queryy);
$resultt = $reqq->fetchAll();

if($resultt){

    //$listShk = array();
    $listShk = '';
    foreach($resultt as $kv) {
        $id_shksj = $kv['id_shksj'];
        $silsila_ar = $kv['silsila_ar'];

        // get sheikh name
        //$queSh = 'SELECT shk_fname, shk_lname FROM sheikh_tbl WHERE shk_tran = "'.$main_shk.'"';

        $queSh = 'SELECT shk_fname, shk_lname, shk_tran 
                  FROM sheikh_tbl 
                  WHERE id_shk = "'.$id_shksj.'"';

    echo $queSh.'</br>';      
    $reqSh = $connexion->query($queSh);
    $resSh = $reqSh->fetchAll();


    foreach($resSh as $aSh)
    {
        $shk_fname = $aSh['shk_fname'];
        $shk_lname = $aSh['shk_lname'];
        $shk_tran = $aSh['shk_tran'];

        $shkFullName = $shk_fname.' '.$shk_lname;

        //$listShk[] = $shkFullName;
        $listShk .= '<a href="Sheikhs/'.$shk_tran.'.html" target="_BLANK">';
        $listShk .= $shkFullName;
        $listShk .= '</a>';
        $listShk .= ' - ';
        $listSheikhs = substr($listShk, 0,-2).'<br />';


    }
}
```

Comment: So what actually is the question/problem

Comment: The thing is, if we found the same album, it should give me a chance whether to combine singers on that album or not, for example My Heart, it should not be combined, however  Lovely it should be combined

Comment: You should have a unique way of identifying each row, if the 'name' column is not unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to acomplish depends on your database structure (sorry, I cannot understand the language of your query). Your rows should have unique identifiers; usually number IDs. You probably have a table that ties albums to singers, right?

```
album_singer
+---------------------+
| album     | singer  |
+---------------------+
| My Heart  | Singer 1|
| My Heart  | Singer 8|
| ...                 |
```

This table should probably just contain the *IDs* of your albums and singers.

```
albums                  singers                 album_singer
+---------------------+ +---------------------+ +----------------------+
| Id      | Name      | | Id     | Name       | | album_id | singer_id |
+---------------------+ +---------------------+ +----------------------+
| 201     | My Heart  | | 101    | Singer 1   | | 201      | 101       |
| 202     | My Heart  | | 102    | Singer 8   | | 202      | 102       |
| ...                 | | ...                 | | ...                  |
```

If this is your structure, your query should be something like:

```
SELECT albums.name as album_name, 
       singers.name as singer_name
FROM album_singer 
JOIN albums on album_singer.album_id = albums.id
JOIN singers on album_singer.singer_id = singer.id

# Output:
# +------------------------------------+
# | album_name    | singer_name        |
# +------------------------------------+
# | My Heart      | Singer 1           |
# | My Heart      | Singer 2           |
# +------------------------------------+
```

Comment: the result of my query: **SELECT silsila_ar, id_shksj
FROM mariyat_silsila
JOIN mariyat_silsila_join ON mariyat_silsila.ids = mariyat_silsila_join.id_silsilaj WHERE mariyat_silsila.silsila_tran = "My Heart"
LIMIT 0 , 30** is something like album name is My Heart and singer id is 370 and again My Heart and singer id is 375, I think my table structure as the same as your table above

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful?

```
//Assuming you are connected to the database...

$album_query = "SELECT id, album FROM album_table ORDER BY id";
$album_results = mysqli_query($database_connection, $album_query);

// Create while loop listing the albums. 
while(list($id, $album) = mysqli_fetch_array($album_results, MYSQLI_NUM)){
    echo 'Album -' . $album . '<br>';
    echo 'Singers - ';

    // Then create another query based on the first loop's album name.
    // *note - would maybe be easier to do this with id's instead of names.
    // If there are no common fields, perhaps you could set a variable from a JOIN in the first query. ?
    $singers_query = "SELECT singer_id, singer_name, album
                      FROM singers_table
                      WHERE album = ' . $album . ' ";
    $singers_results = mysqli_query($database_connection, $singers_query);

        //Now create another while loop to nest inside the album loop.
        while(list($singer_id, $singer_name, $album)=mysqli_fetch_array($singers_results, MYSQLI_NUM)){
            echo  $singer_name . ', ';
        }
    echo '<br><br>';
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your idea